# Page is refreshed instead of showing bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Actually i'm trying to show a bootstrap modal if the username and password are incorrect, the website is in ASPX and codebehind is in VB.NET

The issue is that after i'm checking if the user exist or not in debug the pointer enter in the function that should view the modal but instead of showing it the page is refreshed.

Here is my method from onClick

```
Protected Sub loginBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If UserExists(username.Value, password.Value) Then
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Value, True)
    Else
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", True)
    End If

End Sub
```

While here is the script from the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Every time you execute a server function, the page need to refresh. Do a view source, see if your RegisterStartupScript is there, if it is then it's possible that openModal() is called before the modal\jquery\bootstrap even have time to load.

Comment: @the_lotus actually after changing ScriptManager to ClientScript all works

Comment: Happy to see you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'else' condition returns true

And Try this,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Popup", "openModal();", true);
```